# Field of view/ convexity map

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, geometry, convex

On a shape from a logical image, I am trying to extract the field of view from any point inside the shape on matlab :

[image]

I tried something involving to test each line going through the point but it is really really long.(I hope to do it for each points of the shape or at least each point of it's contour wich is quite a few times)

I think a faster method would be working iteratively by the expansion of a disk from the considered point but I am not sure how to do it.

How can I find this field of view in an efficient way?

Any ideas or solution would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'field of view'? Can you elaborate and maybe show an image. Are you looking for the minimal distance to the edge?

Comment: I added a picture. I am looking for all the locations accessible by the point with a straight line. (the shape thing was to be more precise but it may be too much here)

Comment: I think I have a code that does just that. Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: yes I have the version 8.1. How does the code works? I can give it a try with a few indications.

Comment: I have the last version now if it changes anything

Comment: Sorry it took me some time, see my answer and the linked function available for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach (the principle behind [the function I wrote, available on Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48646-radialshadow)):

I created this test image and an arbitrary point of view:

```
testscene=zeros(500);
testscene(80:120,80:120)=1;
testscene(200:250,400:450)=1;
testscene(380:450,200:270)=1;

viewpoint=[250, 300]; 
imsize=size(testscene); % checks the size of the image
```

It looks like this (the circle marks the view point I chose):

[image: scene]

The next line computes the longest distance to the edge of the image from the viewpoint:

```
maxdist=max([norm(viewpoint), norm(viewpoint-[1 imsize(2)]), norm(viewpoint-[imsize(1) 1]), norm(viewpoint-imsize)]);

angles=1:360; % use smaller increment to increase resolution
```

Then generate a set of points uniformly distributed around the viewpoint.:

```
endpoints=bsxfun(@plus, maxdist*[cosd(angles)' sind(angles)'], viewpoint);

for k=1:numel(angles)
        [CX,CY,C] = improfile(testscene,[viewpoint(1), endpoints(k,1)],[viewpoint(2), endpoints(k,2)]);
        idx=find(C);
        intersec(k,:)=[CX(idx(1)), CY(idx(1))];
end
```

What this does is drawing lines from the view point to each directions specified in the array `angles` and look for the position of the intersection with an obstacle or the edge of the image.

This should help visualizing the process:
[image: intersections]

Finally, let's use the built-in `roipoly` function to create a binary mask from a set of coordinates:

```
FieldofView = roipoly(testscene,intersec(:,1),intersec(:,2));
```

Here is how it looks like (obstacles in white, visible field in gray, viewpoint in red):

[image: final scene]

Comment: np for the time. That's perfect for what I want to do and way faster than what I was doing.

Comment: Note : For the file on Matlab central you may want to use the input image as a mask for the  output "visiblefield" to clean the borders of the shapes in the field of view.

thanks a lot